# Where to store a lot of constants in grails

Tags: grails

I have a lot of string constants like url's that can be changed, so I'd like to know, where to store constants in grails?

**Notes:**

- *Config.groovy* file will be too huge, because of I have more than 100 hardcoded constants.
- Is *enum* the best place in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said can be changed, I wouldn't recommend an `enum`. The `Config.groovy` seems like the most logical place. It's not uncommon to have hundreds of settings inside a full blown Grails application, so I wouldn't worry about the number.

Alternatively, since these can change you may want to consider some type of Domain class and storing them in the database/datastore. Using the [Grails cache plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) you can even have them cached so you aren't having to hit the database each time you want to read the values.

In short, there is nothing wrong with using `Config.groovy` in this case.

Comment: Can I use something like external config file, that will be included in main config?

Comment: You sure can. There is no reason why you couldn't use an external configuration file and have that pull in those values into your application configuration.